# AWS CodeBuild: full clone in cross-account setup

Tags: python, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

Using AWS CDK v2, I'm trying to build a pipeline in one AWS account, say the *tools account*, the input of which is a CodeCommit repository located in another account, say the *dev account* (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/use-aws-codecommit-and-aws-codepipeline-to-deploy-a-ci-cd-pipeline-in-multiple-aws-accounts.html) for more info on the setup). I want to pass `True` for the `code_build_clone_output` arg, i.e.,

```
import aws_cdk
from aws_cdk import aws_codecommit
from aws_cdk import aws_codepipeline_actions
from aws_cdk import pipelines


class MyPipeline(aws_cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope, id):
        super().__init__(scope, id)
        
        my_repository = aws_codecommit.Repository.from_repository_arn(
            scope=self,
            id="MyRepo",
            reposirory_arn="my-repository-arn",
        )
        
        synth = pipelines.CodeBuildStep(
            id="Synth",
            input=pipelines.CodePipelineSource.code_commit(
                repository=my_repository,
                branch="main",
                code_build_clone_output=True,
                trigger=aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitTrigger.POLL,
            ),
            ...
         )

         ...
```

Deploying the pipeline first with `False` for `code_build_clone_output` and then with `True`, the changes are (i) that the `codecommit:GetRepository` permission on the CodeCommit repository under the *dev account* is added to the support role in the *dev account* and (ii) that the `codecommit:GitPull` permission on the same repository is added to the role associated with `CodeBuildStep` (which is located in the *tools account*).

Running the pipeline throws the following error:

> [Container] 2022/08/14 18:22:36 Waiting for agent ping
> [Container] 2022/08/14 18:22:37 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
> authorization failed for primary source and source version XXX

My expectation is that the support role under the *dev account* should be used for suppyling the repository to CodeBuild in the *tools account*. Against this background it seems unreasonable to me that the `codecommit:GitPull` permission is added to the role under the *tools account* (and not the support role under the *dev account*).

My impression is, however, that the *tools account* tries to supply the repository, which results in the error stated above.

My question: What do I have to do to get passing `True` for `code_build_clone_output` working in a cross-account setup as described above?

Comment: Ive not tried this setup, but I would hazard to guess that the CodeBuildStep is the wrong place to gather your source. Look into CodeStar, and how to cross account access that to act as your source (CodeStar can connect directly to repos and provide clones to further steps, such as CodeBuilds, in the pipeline, and I would be surprised if It couldn't cross account)

Comment: however, as for your IAM permissions, you are somewhat correct, i *think* (IAM is a little bit weird at times and some parts I'm still hazy on) - You need two roles: your Tools roll, which must have sts:AssumeRole and your Dev role, which must have the perms needed to pull. You then have to have your Tools role *assume* the dev role during deployment, in order to make that cross account bits work. If its in a codebuild or something you may actually have to assume the role through a CLI command for use inside the codebuilds shell.

Comment: Mm, I played around a bit with CodeStar but can't really get my head around how it could solve my problem. I thought using CodeStar connection to connect with the CodeCommit repository might be a way forward but I don't really see how the two may be brought together. Can you help, @lynkfox?

Comment: Wrt your 2nd comment: I have these two roles, what doesn't seem to happen automatically though is that the *tools role* assumes the *dev role* before cloning. I guess I could just set `code_build_clone_output` to `False`, then assume the *dev role* in the Synth CodeBuild and clone the repository. But I'm trying to avoid this solution because it feels a bit hacky to me.

Comment: CodeStar is a connection service - once you set it up, you can then put the details of the repo in as a codestar source for a pipeline - so the first step becomes CodeStar/repoName and everytime a change is committed to that repo it automatically starts the pipeline. This generates by default a shallow clone of your repo as an Artifact (zip file) that is unpacked by any Code family resource that recieves it as an input source

Comment: as for the roles, I know that inside CodeBuild shells ive still needed to assume the role for any CLI actions ive taken, as those aer coming from a "user" not the service resource where the IAM role is assigned. Ive also had issues with the Pipeline role properly assuming the Stage Role during the pipeline to facilitate assuming the role for cross account steps as well. Its... been interesting. I usually end up to defaulting to either a CLI assume or an SDK assume role (if in a lambda) because it is easier to control.

Comment: Thanks again, @lynkfox. I've now decided to abandon the cross-account setup and deploy the pipeline also in the *dev account*, see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/complete-ci-cd-with-aws-codecommit-aws-codebuild-aws-codedeploy-and-aws-codepipeline/, for example. I have the feeling that CDK tells me in some sense to do so. Plus I can use the following approach to separate code-writing people and AWS infrastructure-managing people: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/cross-account.html

Comment: in my humble opinion, it is best that each account be completely seperate and not interact directly with another. If it needs to, then it does so through APIs, but only from the same env level (ie prod to prod). I try hard to follow this philosophy so that a product in one account never has to worry about the internal setup of another. YMMV good luck!

Comment: That supports what I'm heading for now, right?

Comment: I can't tell you for certain as I dont know all your project details, but it is how my teams product is set up.